Hide Cameo placeholders in the resulting PDF when a PowerPoint presentation is exported
I added the Cameo placeholders to all slides in in a PowerPoint file, then I exported it to a PDF.
The resulting PDF file has the Cameo placeholders and it's awkward because pages looks ugly.
Is there a way to hide or remove automatically Cameo placeholders in the resulting file when a PowerPoint presentation is exported to a PDF ?
